# Как обратиться к webBrowser который находится в пользовательском элементе управления? #C Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, form

При нажатии на кнопку должно появляется окно с выбором документа, формата "PDF", далее открываться в окне браузера, формы.

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = 
             Path.Combine(
                Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                "Docs");
        openFileDialog1.FileName = 
            Path.Combine(
            Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            "C:\\Users\\admin\\source\\repos\\MSUN\\MSUN\\Docs\\РПДУ\\",
            "Основы теории радиопередающих устройств.pdf");

       if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           webBrowser1.Navigate(openFileDialog1.FileName);
       }
    }
```

Ошибка *Имя "webBrowser1" не существует в текущем контексте.

Но так как webBrowser находиться в пользовательском элементе управления это создаёт проблему.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `WebBrowser` (Internet Explorer 11) устарел и более не поддерживается в интернете. Используйте `WebView2` (Edge). https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

Answer (score 0):

Если webBrowser1 на форме, но внутри чего-то другого, то проверить, что он public. Ну и нужно полный путь к нему указывать: MyCustomControl.webBrowser1