# возникает ошибка при открытии карт в браузере в windows forms

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void gMapControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textbox1 = textBox1.Text;
        string textbox2 = textBox2.Text;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();
            queryaddress.Append("https://www.google.by/maps/@53.9770381,30.4071148,4232m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=ru&entry=ttu");
            if (textbox1 != string.Empty)
            {
                queryaddress.Append(textBox1 + "," + "+");
            }
            if (textbox2 != string.Empty)
            {
                queryaddress.Append(textbox2 + "," + "+");
            }
            webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void splitContainer1_Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1522549/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-webbrowser-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb/1522583#1522583 WebBrowser (Internet Explorer 11) устарел. Используйте WebView2 (Edge). https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

Comment: Используйте `WebView2`, `WebBrowser` устарел https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms